# extra www's are added to the domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have modified the .`htaccess` file to force *https*. Now, I can not load my website anymore. When I open it, it automatically changes to `www.www.example.com`.

I have removed the .`htaccess` file but still problem not solved.

Here is the incriminated htaccess code:

```
Options All -Indexes 
DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html 

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 

# Force HTTPS on the subdomains/subdirectories login or admin 
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(login|admin)\. [NC] 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(login|admin)\. [NC,OR] 
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

# Force WWW if no subdomain is given 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Could you complete your question by adding your htaccess content (the part you modified) ?

Comment: i have removed this whole code. that means , i am not using any .htaccess codes.

Comment: would you please provide a htaccess code ?
or is this because of the .htaccess file misconfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your htaccess code, which is wrong. Once removed, you still have the issue because of your browser's cache. Try clearing it and then try again, should be OK.

A working version of your code would be:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 

# Force HTTPS on the subdomains/subdirectories login or admin 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(login|admin)\. [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(login|admin)/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

# Force WWW if no subdomain is given 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}::s on::(s) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```